Computing and Visualizing Linear Trends in Ocean Temperature Data
I have a dataset containing ocean temperature values for the time period 1950-2022, covering the entire globe. My goal is to calculate the linear trend for each surface grid box and visualize the results as a two-dimensional map (longitude versus latitude).How can I make loop through each grid box in the dataset and use numpy.polyfit to obtain the linear trend coefficient for each box?I used this code
After extracting the necessary variables (time, longitude, latitude, and ocean temperature) from the dataset, I plan to follow these steps:
for i in range(lon):
for j in range(lat):
Temp_box = temp[:, j, i]
    trend_coefficients = np.polyfit(time, Temp_box, deg=1)
    trend[j, i] = trend_coefficients[0]

plt.contourf(lon,lat,trend,cmap='PuBu')

Please edit your question to make it a minimal reproducible example. Include at least a subset (or toy example) of the data if they are not publicly available. Also tell us what you have attempted, what are the results you get from it, and what was expected instead. In this way, it will be easier for you to receive valuable advice!

If your data is arranged in a 3D array with axes x, y and t you can address a geo-located time series as temperature_time_series = z[x, y].
The following code shows you how you can use Numpy to fit a linear trend to each time series using a list comprehension.
In [49]: %reset -f
    ...: 
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: import numpy as np
    ...: fit = np.polynomial.Polynomial.fit
    ...: 
    ...: # generate data
    ...: W, H, D = 4, 5, 8
    ...: x = np.arange(W) ; y = np.arange(H)
    ...: z = np.array([[np.linspace(0, X+Y, D) for X in x] for Y in y])
    ...: 
    ...: # compute trends
    ...: rD = np.arange(D) # or matbe rD = np.arange(Year_min, Year_max+1)
    ...: trends = np.array([[fit(rD, col, 1).coef[1] for col in row] for row in z])
    ...: 
    ...: # print trends
    ...: for row, Y in zip(trends, y):
    ...:     print('   '.join("(%d, %d, %.2f)"%(X, Y, T) for T, X in zip(row, x)))
    ...: #
    ...: 
(0, 0, 0.00)   (1, 0, 0.50)   (2, 0, 1.00)   (3, 0, 1.50)
(0, 1, 0.50)   (1, 1, 1.00)   (2, 1, 1.50)   (3, 1, 2.00)
(0, 2, 1.00)   (1, 2, 1.50)   (2, 2, 2.00)   (3, 2, 2.50)
(0, 3, 1.50)   (1, 3, 2.00)   (2, 3, 2.50)   (3, 3, 3.00)
(0, 4, 2.00)   (1, 4, 2.50)   (2, 4, 3.00)   (3, 4, 3.50)

In [50]: 

